# How to find the difference in non-consecutive rows that are grouped?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with several thousand records. My dataframe looks like this:

```
Row     ID     OBS      Dist_cover
1       2       1           60
2       2       0          140
3       2       0           15
4       2       0          147
5       2       0           37
6       2       0           89
7       3       1          239
8       3       0           62
9       3       0           11
10      3       0          193
```

I need to find the **difference** in the `Dist_cover` between the "1" and "0" `OBS` values... but grouped by `id`. Essentially, I am looking for the difference between [1,4] - [2,4], [1,4] - [3,4], [1,4] - [4,4], [1,4] - [5,4], [1,4] - [6,4] AND [7,4] - [8,4], [7,4] - [9,4], [7,4] - [10,4], etc. I have tried various approaches with the dplyr (mutate) and data.base package, but have only figured out how to run consecutive rows and can't figure out how to group by `id`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

What you want can be done with `ave`, grouping `Dist_cover` by `ID`.

Note that though the question states that there should be grouping by `OBS`, this is really not needed. The `OBS` equal to 1 is always the first, like it is (implicitly) stated in the question. The OP wants the *"difference between [1,4] - [2,4], [1,4] - [3,4], etc"*.

```
ave(dat$Dist_cover, dat$ID, FUN = function(x) x - x[1])
#[1]    0   80  -45   87  -23   29    0 -177 -228  -46
```

**Data.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Row = 1:10, ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), OBS = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
Dist_cover = c(60L, 140L, 15L, 147L, 37L, 89L, 239L, 62L, 
11L, 193L)), .Names = c("Row", "ID", "OBS", "Dist_cover"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: @Hack-R Yes, I know, but the `OBS` equal to 1 is always the first, like it is (implicitly) stated in the question. The OP wants the *"difference between [1,4] - [2,4], [1,4] - [3,4], etc"*.

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'ID', subset the 'Dist_cover' where 'OBS' is 1 (assuming there is only a single instance of 1 for each ID), subtract it from the 'Dist_covert', and `filter` the values where 'OBS' is 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = Dist_cover[OBS==1] - Dist_cover) %>% 
  # if OBS is 1 occurs always as the first observation for ID
  # mutate(Diff = first(Dist_cover) - Dist_cover) %>% 
  filter(OBS == 0)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row = 1:10, ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), OBS = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Dist_cover = c(60L, 140L, 15L, 147L, 37L, 89L, 239L, 62L, 
    11L, 193L)), .Names = c("Row", "ID", "OBS", "Dist_cover"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```